# Convert a 40 byte long data frame from hex to binary and subsequently to decimal

Tags: c++, c

I am an amateur at software programming. 
However, I have a task to convert a dataframe that is 40 bytes long and in hex values to be converted to binary values and subsequently into decimal values. I tried converting the values from hex to binary after reading them byte by byte. It didn't work quite effectively as some of the data in the frame are not constituted of a single byte.

Let me explain a little in detail. I have a 40 byte long data frame that reads in hex like this:

```
0     40    ffffff82    2     0     0     28    6d
ffffffaf    ffffffc8    0     41    0     8     78    8
72    17    16    16    0     42    0     2
1     2     1     16    ffffffff    ffffffff    0     43
0     0     3     0     0     2     8     0
```

The reason I do not prefer converting these data by reading one byte at a time is because every byte displayed may not essentially imply a meaning. Please read on to understand what I mean by this.
For example:

- 1st to 6th byte represent data that are just 1 byte each. 1st byte is status, 2nd byte is unit voltage, 3rd being unit current and so forth.
- Whereas when it comes to 7th and 8th byte represent a 2 byte data, unit SOC, meaning, unit SOC is a 16 bit data.
- 9th, 10th and 11th byte together indicate Module 1 cell failure information, i.e, the failure information is a 24 bit data.
- 12th,13th and 14th byte together indicate Module 2 cell failure information etc.

This being the case, how can I convert the incoming data frame into binary and subsequently to decimal without reading them byte after byte.

I would appreciate if this is something someone may be able to lend a helping hand with.

Comment: a) Format the question. b) Provide sample input and output. c) Provide the code you have written.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: I would appreciate if somebody could post their inputs or code snippets in C/C++.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve] .  We don't write code for you here or do homework, we answer well-written and specific programming questions.

Comment: "without doing it byte by byte" - so you mean you want to know how to read more than one byte at once into an int, say? It's probably easiest to read each byte separately and then use `<< 8` to shift one and `|` to combine the values. If the endianness of the data matches the endianness of your system you could e.g. make an `int* pointer at the right point in your buffer and read a value in one go, but it's easiest to stick to the bytes. Also beware of the negative ones, the ones with lots of leading FFs - you'll probably have to `& 0xff` those to get them back to eight bits for combination.

Comment: Yes! That is what I intended to ask. Apologies if my phrasing was bad. My question should have rather been phrased as "How can I read multiple bytes of data at once for the conversion."   Also I would appreciate if you may be able to throw a little more light on the ones with leading fffs. What did you mean by I will have to "0xff them to  get them back to eight bits for combination"?

Comment: The deal with those leading ff's is that they're not really there.  Rup was suggesting doing `& 0xff` to mask them back off, but that's not necessary if you treat them properly from the beginning.  That's why my answer uses a buffer of, and a pointer to, *unsigned* characters.  If you have a plain `char` value, and if it's signed, and if you print it using `printf` and `%x` (as it appears you did here), a value like `0x82` will get sign-extended and print as `ffffff82`', and this can be very confusing at first.  But if you use type `unsigned char`, no sign extension happens, and it's fine.

Comment: I see! I get an intuitive idea now.

Comment: The problem with providing you with snippets is that C/C++ is not a language.  Decide on your single language, C **or** C++.  They are distinct languages.  For example, C++ has `std::string` and `std::vector` and in C you can have a variable called *class*.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have read your data frame into a buffer like this:

```
unsigned char inputbuffer[40];
```

Set a pointer pointing to the beginning of the buffer:

```
unsigned char *p = inputbuffer;
```

You can extract single-byte fields trivially:

```
int status = *p++;        /* first byte */
int maxvoltage = *p++;    /* second byte */
int current = *p++;       /* third byte */
```

A two-byte field is only slightly more complicated:

```
int soc = *p++;
soc = (soc << 8) | *p++;
```

This reads two bytes for `soc`, concatenating them together as firstbyte+secondbyte.  That assumes that the data frame uses what's called "big endian" byte order (that is, most-significant or "biggest" byte first).  If that gives you crazy values, it's likely that the data uses "little endian" order, in which case you can flip the bytes around, yielding secondbyte+firstbyte, by reading them like this instead:

```
int soc = *p++;
soc = soc | *p++ << 8);
```

Alternatively, you can dispense with the pointer `p`, and access various bytes out of the `inputbuffer` array directly, although in that case you need to remember that arrays in C are 0-based:

```
int status = inputbuffer[0];      /* first byte */
int maxvoltage = inputbuffer[1];  /* second byte */
int current = inputbuffer[2];     /* third byte */

int soc = (inputbuffer[6] << 8) | inputbuffer[7];
```

or

```
int soc = inputbuffer[6] | (inputbuffer[7] << 8);
```

You can almost follow the same pattern for your 24-bit fields, except that for portability (and especially if you're on an old 16-bit machine) you need to take care to use a `long int`:

```
long int module_1_cell_failure = *p++;
module_1_cell_failure = (module_1_cell_failure << 8) | *p++;
module_1_cell_failure = (module_1_cell_failure << 8) | *p++;
```

or

```
long int module_1_cell_failure = *p++;
module_1_cell_failure |= (*p++ << 8);
module_1_cell_failure |= ((unsigned long)*p++ << 16);
```

or

```
long int module_1_cell_failure =
    inputbuffer[8] | (inputbuffer[9] << 8) |
        ((unsigned long)inputbuffer[10] << 16);
```

Comment: Hi Steve. Thank you for the inputs. I truly appreciate your help. Would this method also work with those pieces with 3 bytes of data implying a meaningful information? As in the case of 9th, 10th and 11th bytes representing cell failure. How would you suggest I concatenate them?

Comment: @PRAO Refresh the page to see the longer answer.